# Hamburger menu not working when i try to open it

Tags: javascript, html

im working on a website for school.
The problem is: My hamburger menu is not opening (btw it only shows up on small screens).
Does anyone know why?

Im using HTML5 (CSS3&Javascript)

Thank you in advance.

HTML code (for the menu)

```
<body>
    <nav>
        <header>
            <div class="logo">
                <h4>Daan</h4>                   
            </div>
        </header>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li>
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="html/5grootstesteden.html">5 grootste steden</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="html/overmij.html">Over mij</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="html/opmaak.html">Opmaak</a>
            </li>   
            <li>
                <a href="html/jquery.html">Jquery</a>
            </li>   
            <li>
                <a href="html/canvas.html">Canvas</a>
            </li>   
            <li>
                <a href="html/gimp.html">GIMP</a>
            </li>   
            <li>
                <a href="html/schoolexamen.html">Schoolexamen</a>
            </li>   
            <li>
                <a href="html/contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>   
        </ul>
        <div class="burger">
            <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
            <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS3 code (to transform the menu to a hamburger one on small screens)

```
nav{ 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around; 
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh; 
    background-color: #2E4053;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.logo{ 
    color: slategrey;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Cookie';
 }

 .nav-links{
     display: flex !important; 
     justify-content: space-around;
     width: 80%;
     padding:30px;
 }
.nav-links li{
    list-style: none; 
    
}
 .nav-links a{
     color: rgb(247, 245, 248);
     text-decoration: none;
     letter-spacing: 3px;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 14px;
 }

 .burger{
     display: none;
     cursor: pointer;
 }

 .burger div{
    width: 25px;
     height: 3px;
     background-color: white;
     margin: 5px;
     transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1000px){
    body{
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .nav-links{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0rem;
        height: 100%;
        top: .75rem; 
        background-color: #2E4053;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }
    .nav-links li{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .burger{
        display: block;
    }
}
.nav-active{ 
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

.toggle .line1{
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0px,6px);

}
.toggle .line2{
    opacity: 0;

}
.toggle .line3{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px,-14px);
}
```

JS code

```
   const navSlide = () => { 
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links'); 
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li')

burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
```

});
}

navSlide();

Comment: Appears to work fine (https://jsfiddle.net/6ok3q79v/) what problem are you having and can you include a [mcve]

Comment: BTW it only shows up on a small screen as thats what you told it to do. See css starting `@media screen and (max-width:1000px){`

Comment: your code works well for me. please explain more specifically under what circumstances the menu does not open.

Comment: thank you all for answering. The problem was that <script> was in my head instead of my body :).

Answer (score 0):

Steps to debug:

1. Have you linked you JavaScript file?

   < script src="yourFileName.js"></ script>
2. Have you made sure all appropriate areas in JS have a closing (;)? It seems like you had one missing here.

   const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');
3. Have you linked to your css?

   < link rel="stylesheet" href="#yourFileName.css">

These may be the issues you are facing if you have functionality in your provided link.

Also spaces were added in front of link, script and script closing to have them viewable you can backspace in your editor.

Comment: thank you all for answering. The problem was that <script> was in my head instead of my body :).